# Count number of times a GPIO is high and configure labels

Tags: python, testing, tkinter, counter, gpio

I am totally new to python and I want to create a simple interface in tkinter which will receive a total of 5 signals (through the same GPIO) indicating that the test to be performed was correct.
At the moment I have managed to make a label change if the GPIO is HIGH or LOW, but I want each label to stay ON after receiving the corresponding signal and restarting at the end.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)


class gpio(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(root, *args, **kwargs):
            tk.Tk.__init__(root, *args, **kwargs)
            root.title("Tester")
            root.geometry('600x600')
            
            
#TEST-1        
            root.labeltest1= tk.Label(root, text=("TEST #1"), bg="black", fg="white")
            root.labeltest1.grid(row = 4,column = 0)

            root.test1status = tk.Label(root, text = "")
            root.test1status.grid(row = 4,column = 2)

#TEST-2        
            root.labeltest2= tk.Label(root, text=("TEST #2"), bg="black", fg="white")
            root.labeltest2.grid(row = 5,column = 0)

            root.test2status = tk.Label(root, text = "")
            root.test2status.grid(row = 5,column = 2)

#TEST-3        
            root.labeltest3= tk.Label(root, text=("TEST #3"), bg="black", fg="white")
            root.labeltest3.grid(row = 6,column = 0)

            root.test3status = tk.Label(root, text = "")
            root.test3status.grid(row = 6,column = 2)
            
#TEST-4        
            root.labeltest4= tk.Label(root, text=("TEST #4"), bg="black", fg="white")
            root.labeltest4.grid(row = 7,column = 0)

            root.test4status = tk.Label(root, text = "")
            root.test4status.grid(row = 7,column = 2)
         
#TEST-5        
            root.labeltest5= tk.Label(root, text=("TEST #5"), bg="black", fg="white")
            root.labeltest5.grid(row = 8,column = 0)

            root.test5status = tk.Label(root, text = "")
            root.test5status.grid(row = 8,column = 2)
        
            
            root.update_gpio()
                    
        def update_gpio(root):
            rt1 = ('      TEST OK      ' if GPIO.input(2) else '      --     ')
            root.test1status.configure(text=rt1, bg ="yellow")
            root.after(200, root.update_gpio)
            
             
if __name__== "__main__":
    app = gpio()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: What are the *"corresponding signals"* for other labels?

Comment: Signal #1 - test1status /
Signal #2 - test2status /
Signal #3 - test3status....

Comment: What I means is how do you get those signal values, like `GPIO.input(2)` for `test1status`?

Comment: I only get 5 pulses form the source, so what I'm trying is if I have 1 pulse that will be for the `test1status`, if I get 2 pulses the counter will be "2". So it needs to be something like `rt2 = ('      TEST OK      ' if counter = 2 else '      --     ')
            root.test1status.configure(text=rt1, bg ="yellow")`

Comment: You have to monitor the line.